# Proper instruction on saving images in photoshop for xcode

Tags: xcode, image, photoshop

been working with xcode for about week. working with a project from github with images already added. i want to change the design of those images, so

ive been opening in finder, open with photoshop, change the design, save as then the photo shows up in xcode in its correct place, however the image does not show up in simulator.

can you please go through the proper process of saving images for xcode?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please ignore the "general computing and hardware" close message, that's wrong and I didn't select that. If possible, you might want to include additional information by either explaining further or screenshots relevant to the issue you're having. For more information, see [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Well photoshop the picture (obviously)

2.Go to "file" and then go to "save as"

3.When you are there save the image as a "png" (you select to change it to png next to where it says "format")

4.Then drag that png file into the "supporting file" in your xcode project.

5.From there you go to the "imageview" and select the "png" file

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. the problem was rather than scrolling down and selecting  PNG, i would type png by deleting the default .jpg in the save as... field and replacing the ending with .png manually. for some reason that method does not work. anyway cheers.

Comment: Alright just glad I could help